# Inject Relationships into Ember Payload

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a component that shows and creates comments for a post, this component has a form for creating the new comments and sends them via POST to the backend, the normal payload would be:

```
{
  data: {
    attributes: {
      created_at: "foo",
      autor: "foo",
      text: "foo"
    },
    relationships: {
      post: {
        data: { type: "posts", id: 1234 },
        id: "1234",
        type: "loans"
      }
    },
    type: "comment"
  }
}
```

The problem comes when you need to use the component in another view and more importantly when the name of the model is different, to say posts_breakdown, in this case, the payload would be:

```
    { data: {
        attributes: {
          created_at: "foo",
          autor: "foo",
          text: "foo"
        },
        relationships: {
          post: {
            data: null
          }
        },
        type: "comment"
      }
    }
```

Clearly, in comments, there is no relation posts_breakdown, the first thing that I tried to add this relation to the model with `posts_breakdown: belongsTo (posts_breakdown)`.

The problem is, that the backend can't recognize it and is not possible to modify it.
The backend is taking the values on the relationships to relate the comment with the post (post_id field into comment table)

`My question`: Is there some way to "trick" the backend and/or modify the payload, so think that the post_breakdown model is posted?

Below is a representation of how I have the defined models:

`comment.js:`

```
    export default DS.Model.extend ({
        author: DS.attr (),
        text: DS.attr (),
        created_at: DS.attr (),
        post: DS.belongsTo ('post'),
        posts_breakdown: DS.belongsTo ('posts_breakdown'),
    });
```

`posts.js:`

```
    export default DS.Model.extend ({
        text: DS.attr (),
        created_at: DS.attr (),
        author: DS.attr (),
        comments: DS.hasMany ('comments'),
    });
```

`post_breakdown.js`

```
    export default DS.Model.extend ({
        most_commented_post: DS.attr (),
        last_commented_post: DS.attr (),
        frequent_users: DS.attr (),
        comments: DS.hasMany ('comments'),
    });
```

Comment: Write a serializer to transform the payload you send to the server

Comment: Hi, many thanks, this is that i need :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i already figured out the way to modify the payload send it to the backend.
Ember have Serializers!

Following this guide, i can modify the data into the payload, erase it, add it or whatever i need:

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-serializers/

I my case, firs i need to add the relationship into the comment's model, in this line:

```
`posts_breakdown: DS.belongsTo ('posts_breakdown')`
```

then generate a serializer for comment's model with ember-cli:

```
`ember generate serializer comment`
```

finally, into the serializer if the payload contains data into the post_breakdown relationship, delete it and pass it to post relationship, in this way, the payload was the same:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  /*
  This two functions, are necesary because Ember Data changes the underscore
  between variable names by dashes. In fact, it's a Ember suggestion.
  */
  keyForAttribute: function (key) {
    return key;
  },

  keyForRelationship: function (key) {
    return key;
  },

  serialize(snapshot, options) {
    let json = this._super(...arguments);
    /* This makes possible to store comments when the comments-panel-loan component is used
    in loan_breakdown view with post_breakdown model:
    */
    if (json.data.relationships.post_breakdown.data) {
      json.data.relationships.loan = {
        data: {
          type: "posts",
          id: json.data.relationships.post_breakdown.data.id }
      };
      delete json.data.relationships.post_breakdown;
    }
    return json;
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you for writing up your solution! Real life serializer examples are super helpful